# How can I judge whether the file (read from dropbox webpage) has been changed or not in Java?

Tags: java, dropbox, last-modified

Now I'm doing a distributed systems homework in Java, so I need to access one copy of configuration file from several computers. And now I could read and parse a shared file from dropbox webpage, like this one: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ysn9yivqj7kwo0w/config.yaml. 
What I want to do is to add a daemon thread to detect whether this file has been changed or not, if changed, I need to re-config every node of system.

But how can I judge whether this file has been changed or not IN PROGRAM, without downloading the whole file and then to do some diff? I think dropbox should add something like timestamps to files, but how can I get access to this timestamp?

Any suggestion is welcome, much thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd look at the content-md5.  So you keep an md5 of your previous version and if they don't match, then download the file.

Comment: Hi paul, thanks for your suggestion. I know what you mean, but how could I calculate the md5 without fetching the whole file? I don't want to download the whole file if nothing changed. So do you mean I could get access to the md5 provided by dropbox?

Comment: Inspect the headers before you download the file.  Look for "Content-MD5"

Comment: Hi Paul again, I've tried what you said, but what I get from headers are list below:null--->[HTTP/1.1 200 OK]
cache-control--->[max-age=0]
etag--->[35n]
Date--->[Thu, 24 Jan 2013 02:06:28 GMT]
Content-Length--->[1188]
accept-ranges--->[bytes]
Content-Type--->[text/plain; charset=ascii]
Connection--->[keep-alive]
Server--->[nginx/1.2.6]
pragma--->[public]
There're no content-md5.....Maybe I misunderstand you? Could you please be more specific? Thanks again!

Comment: I don't think the Etag is the same as MD5, meaning you can't calculate the MD5 on your local copy and then compare it to the Etag and expect to make some assumption based on that. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the [sdk form dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/sdk),
you can get the metadata of a file via

```
    meta = api.metadata(path, 1, null, false, null);
```

and check the last modified date or hash of the file via

```
    meta.hash;
    meta.modified;
```

Comment: Reading the documentation, hash is not the "hash of the file", it's a hash of the metadata so that Dropbox doesn't have to resend info its already sent to the client. Its NOT an indication of the contents of the file itself.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

According to the [API documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs), `/metadata` retrieves file and folder metadata. Compare hash (md5) to check

**URL Structure**: `https://api.dropbox.com/1/metadata/auto/<path>`

Returns the metadata for the file or folder at the given . If  represents a folder and the list parameter is true, the metadata will also include a listing of metadata for the folder's contents.

**Using in Java**

From [Java SDK documentation](http://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v1.7.x/com/dropbox/core/DbxClient.html#getMetadata(java.lang.String))

```
public DbxEntry getMetadata(String path)
                     throws DbxException
Get the file or folder metadata for a given path.
 DbxClient dbxClient = ...
 DbxEntry entry = dbxClient.getMetadata("/Photos");
 if (entry == null) {
     System.out.println("No file or folder at that path.");
 } else {
     System.out.print(entry.toStringMultiline());
 }
```

**Parameters**

path - The path to the file or folder (see DbxPath).

**Returns**

If there is a file or folder at the given path, return the metadata for that path. If there is no file or folder there, return null.

**Throws**

DbxException

**Update**

**Solution 2 (Hacky workaround)**

Unfortunately Dropbox doesn't give hash for files, it only gives for directories. So if you're developing using dropbox API for sync, you can do one of the following

- When downloading the file, copy the rev parameter as that contains the revision number
- Compare last modified for the local and cloud file (Note: Not guaranteed to work always. If 2 people edit file at the same time locally at the exact same time and one of them overwrites the draft file, you might get a false positive).